# CSS error on Safari, it works on Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, browser, safari

I am trying to make a website and was looking at this template (http://www.uipasta.com/wordpress-preview/rolling/).

I really liked the "testimonials" part and was trying that on my code. 
However, I realized that "testimonials" part works totally fine on Chrome with any browser size, but not on Safari. 
All the elements of testimonials get overlapped on Safari when I first open it up... It's funny because if I shrink or enlarge the browser and keep doing it like that, the elements stop overlapping and work perfect like on Chrome.

I tried to modify some stuff in css files and tried to find a bug. 
But, all the attempts failed in vain... Can someone help me out with this?

LOL I can't even upload more than 2 links yet, because i don't have enough reputation... Here is how it looks on Safari, https://i.stack.imgur.com/kza7d.jpg
but yeah that's how it looks on Safari when it should be clean carousel moving objects.

Comment: What happens when you refresh on any screen size? Does it work fine?

Comment: Can I see your code demo?